# Adding Submit button on the second page did not work

Tags: html, upload, submit

I am working on a demo project that uploads a photo and returns with the name of the person. So basically I use HTML and it consists of 2 pages, the first page - for users to upload photos and submit it while the second page - the recognized name in the photo will be shown. I have a web service that I need to enable it for face recognition to work. The first page has a submit button, which is to upload the photo, but I wanted the submit button to be on the second page as well so that the users can submit another photo, without the need to go back to the first page. I copied the HTML code in the first page to second page,

```
<form>
   <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
        <button class="btn">Submit</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

the structure of the submit button is there. But it doesn't work, while it worked for the first page, it did not work on the second page. What could be the problem? Let me know if u need more clarification I would be happy to do so

The Code for the first page
[Page 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18p2jDXBW28eEv8XIrloKyLZkb-Q5IWFB)

The Code for the second page 
[Page 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DGAxaXcf8jZkB_1VTYeNWoYREOHzv029)

The codes for both pages are almost the same.

Comment: the form and submit button must be in the same page and the submit button must be wrapped with form element

Comment: @Moshiur Hey I've added the form element, you can see it from the latest post edit. Before <form> was added, pressing submit did not do anything, after adding it, when i pressed the submit button, it went back to the first page.... Why is that?

Comment: show us both of your pages thus we can understand where you stuck

Comment: @Moshiur I've edited in my post with the attached drive link. Please check it out :)

Comment: on 2nd page all inputs must be within the form tag, you have placed ``` <input type="file">``` outside of the form

Comment: @Moshiur I tried it. When I clicked on the Submit button, it went back to Page 1....

Comment: looks like you have not defined form action, so how are you submitting the form?

Comment: @Moshiur for this matter can i personally private message u or do you have any social platform that i can contact u with?

Comment: @Moshiur i used the method <form method="POST"> but still i cant make it work... i need help...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207147/discussion-between-moshiur-and-ventuszxc).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add condition when you are submitting and action attribute as well where you want to submit.

```
<form action="upload.php">
   <input type="file" name="file" id="uploadFile" />
   <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

for validation, you need to add some jquery code

```
$(document).on("click", ":submit", function (e) {

 if( document.getElementById("uploadFile").files.length == 0 ){
   alert("no files selected"); // or you can use other approach
   e.preventDefault();
 }

}
```

Comment: Oh, but I have some confusion. The code (which I originally posted) works on first page , but not on the second page. So on the second page I need to add some jQuery code and some condition?

Comment: yes, if you want to add validation, it will be easier to use jquery.

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a try. But for the jQuery code, where should I put it? I beautified it but I have no idea where should I insert the code.